# using useContext hook get "Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>"

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am using `useContext` for my react app, I wrap my parent component with provider and in child component I call useContext to get access to global context and also I use `useDispatch` to dispatch the functions within the context.

```js
export const QuotesContext = React.createContext<QuoteContextInterface>({});
export const QuotesProvider = QuotesContext.Provider;

const ParentComponent = ({}) => {

return (
<QuotesProvider value={{getUsers, users}} >
  <ChildComponent />
</QuotesProvider>
)
}


const ChildComponet = ({}) => {
  const quoteContext = useContext(QuotesContext);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {

  dispatch(quoteContext.getUsers)

 }, [])
}

}
```

the error I get is `Error: Uncaught [Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>]`

also in the error path I see that its is complaining about useDispatch line in child component.

I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are importing `useDispatch` from `react-redux`, while context has nothing to do with this.
To change the state of context, your context needs to have it's own state (with `useReducer` or `useState`).